# How to access the chat from the main page?

Tags: support, chat

I gained recently the "privilege" of talking in chat on TeX.se, but I cannot figure out how can I access to the chat room as there's no indications. I found a very long path by going on all the chats of all communities of Stackexchange, and still (on 55 pages of chats) couldn't find TeX.se one.

So, how can I access chat briefly from my main page? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: *as there's no indications.* there is! in the top and in the bottom.

Comment: if you click on the "StackExchange" at the top left, one of the offered links, on the top line, is "chat".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the dropdown to see the rooms and the main chatroom is available there

[image]

Comment: Seems the fastest way, I was going crazy, thanks!

Comment: Not possible any more (2023). Deep link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=tex.stackexchange.com (found via the other answer: scroll down the page)

Answer (score 6):

Scroll the main page all the way down,

[image]

Comment: Simplest way in my way of thinking would e to use the browser search with the term chat. That would lead to exactly the link you are showing.

Comment: Which browser search ?

Comment: Ctrl + f starts a search window in firefox

Comment: First of all, I don't have firefox. Secondly, what happens if the main page has some posts that use 'chat' word?! :) probably not the simplest way I presume.

Comment: Every browser i know of has some search function. I use it all the time. For me, the question is so very trivial, i cannot believe it exists. Maybe i am just too old.

Comment: But you didn't answer the second question *what happens if the main page has some posts that use 'chat' word?! :)*

Comment: Search for the next result. It really isn't that hard.

Comment: No it isn't hard but do this method in this page, you will end up with 25 matches, good luck for searching for the next result while you know for sure the last is your choice. :)

Comment: Out of the 137,565 questions on the main site, two have the word "chat" in their title. With 15, 30 or 50 questions listed on the front page, the chances of a false positive search results or not very high :)

Comment: @samcarter, I think you are aware of the fact that any word that contains `chat` letters in this order will appear in the results.

Comment: @CroCo Sure, there are some post with words like `Bodenschatz` (this increases the total number of post containing `*chat*` to 409 from 241 for `chat`) but as far as I can see, no additional post with `*chat*` in the title. So my claim stands: I don't think false positives are likely on the front page.

Comment: @CroCo Of course this strategy would fail spectacularly if one of the top users would change his\her username to something like Chatlisle

Answer (score 5):

The icon on the farest right opens a drop down menu. There is a link to the chat

[image: screenshot of the button with marked "chat"]

Answer (score 2):

If you go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/ (click on the large red "TEX" at the top of every page) there is a link at the left hand side:

[image]

Or bookmark the chat :)

Comment: It's not always visible for some reason

Comment: @percusse Really? I virtually always get this link on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ (not on other pages like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) Do you use any add-ons that maybe modify the page content?

Comment: not really I see that link sporadically. It replaces with site ads I think

Comment: @percusse I don't see the ads any more - I thought this was correlated with the reputation, but as you have a way more rep this cannot be.

Comment: Didn't show up in my browser.